# Register WordPress user via Unbounce form

Tags: php, wordpress, user-registration

Apologies up-front for the novice nature of this question...

I am attempting to pass an email captured via an Unbounce landing page form to WordPress and programatically register a new WordPress user.

This is the set-up so far:

1. Unbounce landing page (get.slideheroes.com/testing)
2. Passing the email address via 'post form data to url'
3. Target url is https://www.slideheroes.com/newuser.php
4. PHP (in newuser.php) code as follows:

   ```
   if( null == username_exists( $email ) ) {

     // Generate the password and create the user
     $password = wp_generate_password( 12, false );
     $user_id = wp_create_user( $email, $password, $email );

     // Set the nickname
     wp_update_user(
       array(
         'ID'          =>    $user_id,
         'nickname'    =>    'Trial User'
       )
     );

     // Set the role
     $user = new WP_User( $user_id );
     $user->set_role( 'contributor' );

     // Email the user
     wp_mail( $email, 'Welcome!', 'Your Password: ' . $password );

   } // end if
   ```

Any suggestions as to what (perhaps many things) that I am doing wrong?

Comment: Is there a problem with the behavior? What's the difference between the designed behavior and experienced behavior?

Comment: :-)  Good question.

Experienced behavior = no user is registered, nothing happens, blanck page
Designed behavior = user registered, email sent

Answer (score 0):

In order to get this working you have to include wp-load.php and set the $email variable with the posted value:

```
require_once('/path/to/wp-load.php');

$email = $_POST['email']; // maybe some extra validation if needed

if( null == username_exists( $email ) ) {

  // Generate the password and create the user
  $password = wp_generate_password( 12, false );
  $user_id = wp_create_user( $email, $password, $email );

  // Set the nickname
  wp_update_user(
    array(
      'ID'          =>    $user_id,
      'nickname'    =>    'Trial User'
    )
  );

  // Set the role
  $user = new WP_User( $user_id );
  $user->set_role( 'contributor' );

  // Email the user
  wp_mail( $email, 'Welcome!', 'Your Password: ' . $password );

} // end if
```